# Grant cloning extension for a user

Tags: ee1

I am using the [Cloner extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cloner) with EE 1.7, and I can't work out how to give one of my users access to duplicate and clone an entry.

I know I can do this as a superadmin, but I'm not sure whether I can grant access to a content contributor. Is this possible?

**NB** I'm currently using EE 1.7 (Yes, I know this is outdated).

Comment: Which extension are you using exactly? Can you post a link? To clarify, you want to give a non-superadmin member the ability to clone another member?

Comment: I am using this: [link](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cloner/)

Comment: I'm not familiar with EE 1.x but it looks like Cloner clones entries, not users.

Comment: I should have been more specific - clone entires, not users :) @AndieFairlie

Comment: Anyone help me with a link to the Cloner extension for EE1? It's vanished from their website.

Comment: Here you go, Clayton. Had to dig it up:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1739837/ee/cloner.zip

Answer (score 1):

Have you restricted which sections of the Control Panel the other User Group can access? If so, this is probably what's causing the issue. It's been awhile, but there is at least the "Can access MODULES page" permission, which you may need to enable.

I've mirrored the EE 1.x docs [here](http://metasushi.com/documentation/ee1/) for reference since they have been taken offline. The Groups page is [here](http://metasushi.com/documentation/ee1/cp/admin/members_and_groups/member_groups_edit.html).

Comment: It appears the user can clone their own entries but not an entry somebody else created.